# Angular get CSV file in browser by calling URL

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, microservices, angularjs-ng-click

I have made a Java micro service to export a table from a database into a CSV file and get it in browser by following this: [Downloading a CSV File in Browser by using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100416/downloading-a-csv-file-in-browser-by-using-java)
It works well and I get the file in the browser when I call the URL (by copying and pasting in the browser) :
http://localhost:8080/api/fileDownload/2

In the Angular part when I call the URL in my app I see in the console :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/fileDownload/2
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200
```

In the preview and the response of the console, I also have the content of my file. So it seems everything looks good but the problem is that my browser doesn't download the file automatically.

My controller :

```
vm.downloadFunction=function(){
    FileDownload.download.query({id:2},function(data){
    });
};
```

My view :

```
 <label data-ng-click="addModule.downloadFunction()" class="btn btn-link btn-file">
                    Download <input type="button" class="hidden">
                </label>
```

And the service :

```
voltApp.factory('FileDownload', function ($resource) {
return{
    download:  $resource('/api/fileDownload/:id', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {id:'@id'},isArray:false},
        update:{method: 'PUT'}
    })
};
```

});

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This post was very helpul too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215049/how-to-download-file-using-angularjs-and-calling-mvc-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [ngFileSaver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver)

Example:

**JS**

```
function ExampleCtrl(FileSaver, Blob) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.val = {
    text: 'Hey ho lets go!'
  };

  vm.download = function(text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');
  };
}

angular

      .module('fileSaverExample', ['ngFileSaver'])
      .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['FileSaver', 'Blob', ExampleCtrl]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl as vm">
  <textarea
    ng-model="vm.val.text"
    name="textarea" rows="5" cols="20">
      Hey ho let's go!
  </textarea>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-dark btn-small" ng-click="vm.download(vm.val.text)">
    Download
  </a>
</div>
```